# lighttpd url rewrite to subdomain

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, lighttpd

How does the lighttpd rewrite work for folowing?

`http://example.com/file_46634643.jpg` to `http://sub.domain.com/46634643.jpg`

If it's possible...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. Use mod_rewrite, here is an example:

```
url.rewrite-once = ("^/file_([0-9]+\.jpg)$" => "/$1")
```

Check [Lighttpd's mod_rewrite documentation](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/lighttpd/Docs:ModRewrite) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think mod_rewrite allows you to "rewrite" to another (sub)domain. You could use mod_redirect (but it's a redirect, not a rewrite). Here is a slightly modified version of Bartosz's answer:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "example.com" {
  url.redirect = ( "^/file_([0-9]+\.jpg)$" => "http://sub.domain.com/$1" )
}
```

Check http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/lighttpd/Docs:ModRedirect